# How to connect to Cloud SQL using dart app engine and sqljocky

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, google-cloud-sql, sqljocky

I would like to use the application identifier access control method for allowing my app engine service connect to a Cloud SQL database. The app engine service is written using dart with sqljocky.

In the Developers Console, Storage, Cloud SQL, db instance, Overview tab, there is a link titled "How to connect to your Cloud SQL instance". There, I only see sample code for doing this in PHP, Java and Python. I've tried to find an analogous implementation for dart with no luck.

Can anyone suggest an approach for doing this?

Comment: Internally, it appears that sqljocky makes its connection using RawSocket.connect(host, port);

Comment: If so, you may try to use ServerSocket interface in dart. Not sure if it works in browser, but if it is, it should work

Comment: It appears to me that ServerSocket is for listening. I'm having problems on the sql client end, not the server end. I don't see how this can help.